# PBE With SHA256 and tripleDES Cryptor change byte size?

Tags: c#, encryption, sha256, tripledes

I'm using an updated version of Java's PBEWithMD5andDES to encrypt the ID of a customer.

My new version is PBEWithSHA256AndTripleDES. This works good but I have one issue with it. The end result of my encrypted ID is always 8 bytes which results in an encryption of something like (this just some random number and result to show what I mean) 56872 = 84 FE A5 01 5D 6E 4F 98.

Is it possible to adjust the end result? so that 56872 would result in an encrypted result of say 84 FE A5 01 5D 6E 4F 98 87 FF 3A AA B9 F1?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After investigating the workings of DES, TripleDES and AES I somewhat learned how they work and now understand that it's practically always 8 bytes for DES and TripleDES. 
In order to go to 16 bytes I updated my implementation to now use AES cryptography.